# Input parameters in lambda expressions

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, expression, aggregate

I have this code

```
public static double Average(this ParallelQuery<int> source) {
    return source.Aggregate(
       () => new double[2], 
       (acc, elem) => { acc[0] += elem; acc[1]++; return acc;},
       (acc1, acc2) => { acc1[0] += acc2[0]; acc1[1] += acc2[1]; return acc1; },
       acc => acc[0] / acc[1]);
}
```

It sets some lambda expression with 2 parameters, but my question is how can the program know that `acc` is the array of double and `elem` an element of `source`? There is no assignment

Comment: Perhaps `new double[2]` helps with type inference? :)

Comment: But my question is, how he understand that, for example, acc it's the array and not the element of source?  if i write (elem, acc) instead of (acc, elem) what happens? I can't understand how the parameters works in lambda expressions...

Comment: Parameter names are irrelevant, it's the [method signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd384149(v=vs.100).aspx) that is important. The first parameter in `(acc, elem)` is the accumulator, the second one is the sequence element, but you can name them anything you like in your lambda (as long as you are aware of their order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler infers the type from your first parameter.

Since the method signature is:

```
public static TResult Aggregate<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
    this ParallelQuery<TSource> source,
    Func<TAccumulate> seedFactory,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> updateAccumulatorFunc,
    Func<TAccumulate, TAccumulate, TAccumulate> combineAccumulatorsFunc,
    Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

So, `TSource` is already known to be `int`, and as soon as you pass `() => new double[2]` as the `seedFactory` parameter, it knows that `TAccumulate` is of type `double[]` (because `seedFactory` is a delegate which returns `TAccumulate`).

Similarly, the result of your last delegate (`resultSelector`) will define the result type.

If you are using Visual Studio and hover your mouse over `source.Aggregate`, intellisense will show you how the generic parameters were inferred.

Comment: Ok, thanks,  but now I don't understand what the second delegate does (acc1, acc2) => { acc1[0] += acc2[0]; acc1[1] += acc2[1]; return acc1; } ... I try to replace the body with return null and the result doesn't change...

Comment: @Thomas: you should read PLINQ and ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate docs. The method works by dividing work into parallel tasks (if it chooses so). To avoid locking, each task works on its own set of data (i.e. every task has its own separate instance of the accumulator). The `combineAccumulatorsFunc` is then called at the end to merge all results into a single value. I seriously doubt `null` is a valid result for the combine delegate - although sometimes it's possible that the query gets executed on a single thread (and doesn't combine).

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation for the [ParallelEnumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd384149(v=vs.110).aspx). You define the `TAccumulate` with your seed factory, so the type is known.